# How do I lock my Android using messages service?

Tags: android

This is my Broadcasting Class, it is not locking my device after all. What am I doing wrong?

```
        try
        {

                devicemanager  = (DevicePolicyManager)arg0.getSystemService(arg0.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
            if(bundle!=null)
            {
                final Object[] pdusobj=(Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
                for(int i=0; i<pdusobj.length; i++)
                {
                    android.telephony.SmsMessage currentMessage=android.telephony.SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdusobj[i]);
                    String phonenumber=currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String sendernum=phonenumber;
                    String message=currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                    String compare = "Security...!";
                    Log.i("SmsReceiver","sendernum"+ sendernum+"; message:"+message);
                    int duration=Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    if(compare.equalsIgnoreCase(message))
                    {
                    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(arg0, "   message   "+message, duration);
                    toast.show();

                         devicemanager.lockNow();
                         Toast toas=Toast.makeText(arg0, compare+" = "+message, duration);
                            toas.show();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(arg0, "not matched", 0).show();
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver :"+e);
        }
    }
```

What is a actual problem here? In if condition I want to lock my device every thing is good but my device isn't locking.

I have already given SMS RECEIVE, SMS SEND, and SMS READ permissions in my manifest file.

Comment: which toasts are displayed?

Comment: i have tosted messege text and it is successfully toasted but when i am comparing messege text and string the device dosent locked . i dont know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app needs to be a **Device admin** to call this method. It also must have requested `USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK`.

Comment: how do i make a device admin ? can you please give me a code

Comment: I'm not here to write your code. Read the official documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html or search for other guides. I'm sure there are plenty.

Comment: Thank you it helped me ! :)